# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, typeerror, kdtree

I have two Python Pandas DataFrames. Each DataFrame has the same columns. One df contains historical data that have a target label, and the other contains predictions on current data with a predicted label.

My goal is to individually run a KDTree query for each of the predictions data with respect to the historical data to get a list of the three closest neighbors from the historical data.

The logic I am using to do this is a for loop that adds a row from the current data to the historical data, runs the query, and then adds the next row to the historical data.

Here is my code:

```
fde = fde[features]
locations = []
for row in fde.iterrows():
    temp_elite = fne[features]
    temp_elite = temp_elite.append(row)
    tree = KDTree(temp_elite, metric='euclidean')
    dist, ind = tree.query(temp_elite, k=4)
    print(ind)
    locations.append(ind.tail(1))
print(locations)
```

However, this is my erorr:

```
---> 14     temp_elite = temp_elite.append(row)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

Am I attempting to solve the problem correctly, and any ideas on how to get around this error?

Comment: Not sure what type of data you have there, but `temp_elite = temp_elite.append(row)` will make `temp_elite` as None

Comment: you don't need to assign it to `temp_elite`. `temp_elite.append(row)` will just do the job